# Filter Mail by Custom InternetMessageHeaders

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am able to send mail and add custom internetMessageHeaders. But what I'm attempting to do now is return messages based on filtering to the custom headers I'm adding.

Example:
If I add a custom header to the message for "x-custom-header-productid = x123z" I want to filter and return all messages that have the custom header for x-custom-header-productid that equals x123z. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The header needs to be provisioned in the Mailbox you want to search for it on eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-provision-x-headers-by-using-ews-in-exchange

So in the Graph if you send a Message using that mailbox that would provision it for use in that Mailbox eg

```html
{
    "message": {
        "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
        "body": {
            "contentType": "Text",
            "content": "The new cafeteria is open."
        },
        "toRecipients": [
            {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "address": "youmailbox@domain.com"
                }
            }
        ],
        "singleValueExtendedProperties": [
            {
                "id": "String {00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name X-blah-blah",
                "value": "Food"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You could then search for any messages that arrived (after you provisioned that header)eg which would mean the property would be promoted in the store.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep:ep/id eq 'String {00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name X-blah-blah' and ep/value eq 'Food')
```

Comment: This works! But I have to say, I don't understand why. The namespace guid, in which you have above as 00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046, is this a specific or random id? What I mean is, is that id specific to internet headers namespace? If so, is there a list of namespaces with the corresponding guids?

Comment: Yes it the internet headers guid there is a full list on https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-developer-client-docs/blob/main/docs/outlook/mapi/commonly-used-property-sets.md